# How can I list playlists only within a given iTunes folder with c#?

Tags: c#, itunes

I have the following code:

```
static void ListPlaylists()
    {
        iTunesApp itunes = new iTunesLib.iTunesApp();

        IITLibraryPlaylist mainLibrary = itunes.LibraryPlaylist;


        foreach (IITPlaylist pl in itunes.LibrarySource.Playlists)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(pl.Name);
        }



    }
```

However, I only want to return playlists within a specific iTunes folder. How can I do this?